# How to retrieve saved data in wordpress database

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I have created a custom post type with custom meta box, given the code below, I know it's saved on prefix_postmeta, how could I get this data and display it on a page template?

for example: if I have THIS POST when I view THIS POST I will be able to see this data at the bottom of THIS POST:

> Title: THIS POST
>
> Content: lorem ipsum
>
> Options from meta box: the options

anyone knows how can I do this? of will give the idea or a tutorial how to do this?
any suggestion will be a great help. pls don't vote down. Thank you, stack overflow dudes.

**The code below is the code I used to save the custom meta box's custom fields.**

```
   function survey_questions_meta_save( $post_id ) {
 // Checks save status
$is_autosave = wp_is_post_autosave( $post_id );
$is_revision = wp_is_post_revision( $post_id );
$is_valid_nonce = ( isset( $_POST[ 'survey_questions_nonce' ] ) && wp_verify_nonce( $_POST[ 'survey_questions_nonce' ], basename( __FILE__ ) ) ) ? 'true' : 'false';
// Exits script depending on save status
if ( $is_autosave || $is_revision || !$is_valid_nonce ) {
    return;
}
if ( isset( $_POST[ 'option1' ] ) ) {
  update_post_meta( $post_id, 'option1', sanitize_text_field( $_POST[ 'option1' ] ) );
}
if ( isset( $_POST[ 'option2' ] ) ) {
  update_post_meta( $post_id, 'option2', sanitize_text_field( $_POST[ 'option2' ] ) );
}
if ( isset( $_POST[ 'option3' ] ) ) {
  update_post_meta( $post_id, 'option3', sanitize_text_field( $_POST[ 'option3' ] ) );
}
if ( isset( $_POST[ 'option4' ] ) ) {
  update_post_meta( $post_id, 'option4', sanitize_text_field( $_POST[ 'option4' ] ) );
}
if ( isset( $_POST[ 'option5' ] ) ) {
  update_post_meta( $post_id, 'option5', sanitize_text_field( $_POST[ 'option5' ] ) );
}
}
  add_action( 'save_post', 'survey_questions_meta_save' );
```

Comment: [`get_post_meta()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/) does the trick. Just get your post ID in and you can pull all the post meta data.

Comment: thanks, @dingo_d i have manage to do so, `$meta = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(),'option1',true); `

Comment: @dingo_d could you write a formal answer below sir, so that i can declare it as an  `answer`, so this will be helpful in the future.

Comment: Sure thing :) Just a sec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for [`get_post_meta()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/) function.

In your page you need to retrieve the custom post ID, best using [`get_the_id()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_id/) function.

If you are on `single-{cpt-name}.php` you can just create a simple loop and inside you'll be able to pull all the posts and meta without any trouble.

```
$post_meta = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'option_name', true );
```

more details on redering post meta on [Wordpress Plugin Handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/metadata/rendering-meta-data/).

Comment: This solved the problem, now I can add a number of custom meta boxes with custom fields and can retrieve it easily. No need to create custom db tables and handle sql commands.